# converting mysql columns to bits in a single column

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL table with multiple columns (tinyint) with 0 or 1 values

I want to convert all these values into bits in a single integer column
So a column named column1 will go to MSB another column will set 2nd bit etc...

How do I do it?

Comment: can you explain better? I don't get your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logical shifts `<<` plus a bitwise or `|` operation.

For example:

`SELECT (col1<<16) | (col2<<15) | (col3<<14) | (col4<<13) ...`

MySQL docs [are here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-functions.html).

Comment: As long as a user remembers the order of the columns processed and has no need to do any mass querying of a single bit, this look like a good solution. +1

Comment: You mean bitwise OR | operator.

Thanks ! that was helpful